# 2013 Ford Escape SEL 2ltr Turbo AWD heavy vibration under load

Tags: ford, suspension, vibration, escape

109K miles. Car started shaking on the hwy under load. Climbing any incline with my foot on the gas.

We took it to an independent shop and the diagnosis was struts, shocks, and new tires.

We replaced struts, shocks and replaced all 4 tires. The old tires were 70K mile tires (hard rubber) and were 5 years old and dry cracking with 50K miles on them and still had tread and weren't cupping.  We replaced all 4 tires and got on the highway last week for a road trip and had to stop 2 hr's later at a Ford Dealer. Heavy vibration.

Can feel it on the floor board and the steering wheel. Actually shakes the car.  Especially under load going up any incline.

I can coast down hill at 70 mph and it doesn't shake.  Tells me it's drive line related.

I had a '87 Ford Ranger with a similar shake and it was the u-joints worn out.

Ford Dealer test drove it on the hwy, put it on the lift and checked the rear differential with a stethoscope for noise.  They said they have a tool to scan for driveline issues and all the axles and components are Ok. They said it was the old tires cracking and causing the issue. Thus we replaced all 4.

Driving home for 9 hours on our trip was a nightmare. Shook the whole way only to get worse.

I'm thinking it's the front CV joints worn out and it's play in the needle bearings making the axles spin out of round.  But what do I know! I'm not a mechanic, just a backyard car guy.  The boots aren't ripped and should be still holding grease.  I really don't wan to replace both CV joints, A-arms, engine mounts just throwing parts at this thing.

Anyone with similar experience and have a known fix?  Thank you.

Comment: The known fix is specific to each vehicle - mine was new discs as they had warped...

Comment: Don't negate it might be a torque converter lockup problem. One way to check (at least how I've done it before) is when you start feeling the shaking, let off the gas pedal, then back on it again. This gives the TC a chance to unlock and relock correctly. If this doesn't help, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Drive it in 2nd gear, does it still do it?

Comment: Shifting down to 5th gear from 6th on the hwy under load when shaking didn't help.  Also, taking my foot off the gas and coasting and then gassing it again didn't help with the torque converter.

Comment: UPDATE on my 2013 Ford Escape with the shake under load.  We had the 2 front axle-cv joint assembly's replaced at our local Pep Boys.  Had a mechanic with 40 years in the business test drive it and diagnose.  I believe he also had the car on the lift with someone in the drivers seat put in in gear and brake torqued it to watch the front axles move and believes they were worn at the bearings-joints and there is play.   We drove the car 2 hours today on the HWY over 100 miles and no shakes!